# Unresolved reference adview, adrequest, mobileads

Tags: android, admob

I'm getting an issue in my Android project with Admob.
I added the dependency `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'` and the project builds normally, but (in development time) Android Studio cannot resolve any reference.

`import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest (Unresolved reference: AdRequest)
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView (Unresolved reference: AdView)
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds (Unresolved reference: MobileAds)`

I'm using Android Studio 3.2.1, Kotlin plugin 1.3.11, compileSdkVersion 27, minSdkVersion 15.

Have you ever faced something like that? How could I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Add the dependency via the UI.

1. In Android Studio, go to File > Project Structure.
2. Go to the dependencies tab.
3. On the right hand side add a 'Library Dependency'.
4. Type "com.google.android.gms:play-services" into the searchbox and pick the appropriate dependency.
5. After adding dependency, go to MainActivity and import import com.google.android.gms.ads.*